# How to fix this compile error for std::chrono comparison in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-asio, c++-chrono

I am following the example [ASIO server with timeout](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/timeouts/server.cpp), and the line at function shown here was modified from deadline_timer::traits_type::now() to be std::chrono::steady_clock::now() because I wanted to use standalone ASIO without boost.  ASIO can use standalone with C++11.

```
void check_deadline(deadline_timer* deadline)
{
    if (stopped())
      return;

    // Check whether the deadline has passed. compare the deadline against
    // the current time 
    // I modified this to be std::chrono::steady_clock::now()
    if (deadline->expires_at() <= deadline_timer::traits_type::now())         {
      // deadline is asio::high_resolution_time type
      stop();
    } else {
      // Put the actor back to sleep.
      deadline->async_wait(
          std::bind(&TCP_Session::check_deadline, shared_from_this(), deadline));    
    }
  }
```

### Problem

In VS2015, the compile works, but in Eclipse G++4.9.2, it complains with

```
no match for 'operator<=' (operand types are 
'asio::basic_waitable_timer<std::chrono::_V2::system_clock>::time_point 

aka 
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::system_clock, std::chrono::duration<long long int, std::ratio<1ll, 1000000000ll> > >}'

 and 

'std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock::time_point {aka std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::_V2::steady_clock, std::chrono::duration<long long int, std::ratio<1ll, 1000000000ll> > >}')  TCPSession.h    line 284    C/C++ Problem
```

### Question:

I found that I can only use C++11, not C++14.  So how to fix this in C++11 (no boost, or classic unix C)?

Comment: Well, one of them is from `system_clock` and the other is from `steady_clock`. They are different clocks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately [standalone ASIO](http://think-async.com/Asio/) hasn't defined a `deadline timer` to match [boost ASIO](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html). However, I think you'll find that `asio::steady_timer` should work.

I use the following macros to switch between 'standalone' and 'boost':

```
#ifdef ASIO_STANDALONE
  #include <asio.hpp>
  #define ASIO asio
  #define ASIO_ERROR_CODE asio::error_code
  #define ASIO_TIMER asio::steady_timer
#else
  #include <boost/asio.hpp>
  #define ASIO boost::asio
  #define ASIO_ERROR_CODE boost::system::error_code
  #define ASIO_TIMER boost::asio::deadline_timer
#endif
```

Comment: "Unfortunately standalone ASIO hasn't defined a deadline timer to match boost ASIO. " Hmm, what's http://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.10.6/doc/asio/reference/deadline_timer.html, then?

Comment: @T.C. http://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.10.6/doc/asio/reference/deadline_timer.html documents something that does not exist. Although  `asio 1.10.6` has a  `basic_deadline_timer.hpp` file, it does not actually define `deadline_timer`, see: https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio/issues/82 for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not Boost Asio uses `std::chrono` depends on a preprocesor define (or maybe the define depends on the compiler detected, I don't recall).

The timer that doesn't have this dependency, again as I remember, would be `asio::high_resolution_timer`. Just make sure you use the right combination of clock and timer there.

It seems to me you should verify the actual type of the variable called `deadline` too.